Improper integral convergence with parametric bound
I have an exercise asking for the convergence of an integral with a parametric bound $\alpha$:
$$ \int_0^\alpha \frac{e^{-x}}{x-\sqrt{x}-2} dx$$
The domain of the function I get:
$$ x - 2 \neq \sqrt{x} $$ which gives $x\neq 4,1$ with the condition $x>2$
therefore the domain is $[0,4)\cup(4,+\infty)$
We then have to study the neighbourhood of $U(4)$ and $U(\infty)$.
In the case of $U(4)$:
$$ f(x) \sim \frac{e^{-4}}{x-\sqrt{x}-2}$$
My question is basically how do I evaluate it? Which power of $x$ should I consider since it's at the denominator?

As a hint, write the integrand as $$\frac{\sqrt{x}+2}{\sqrt{x}+1}\cdot\frac{e^{-x}}{x-4}.$$

@SangchulLee so this would mean that it diverges in U(4) right?
Because the proposed solution in my notes is: it diverges only if $\alpha > 4$ and converges otherwise because f is continuos. But I don't understand why

Indeed the integral diverges for $\alpha \geq 4$. I am not sure why the solution did not include $\alpha=4$, but clearly the integral diverges even in that case.

oh yeah right I am such an idiot I kept reading converges instead of diverges. How did you re-write the integrand? Because I can find my way back from your hint to the integrand but I wouldn't know how to get there starting from the integrand itself.
